# Program for Typedef Structure look up Keeps Crashing

Tags: c

I am trying to write a console application where the user enters in a City then the program looks up the city name in a typedef structure and proceeds to display the city's latitude and longitude coordinates. I have zero errors displaying for the program, but it seems that each time I enter a city and press enter the console application will display city not found and then close out. Here is the code with a few of the cities from the typdef structure (full structure contains 200 variables).

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 



#define MAX_CITY_LEN   35

typedef struct { 
            char  name[MAX_CITY_LEN];
            float latitude;
            float longitude;
           } PLACE_T;

PLACE_T places[] =
     {{"Aberdeen,Scotland",57.15,-2.15},
      {"Adelaide,Australia",-34.92,138.6},
      {"Albany,NY,USA",42.67,-73.75},
      {"Albuquerque,NM,USA",35.08,-106.65},
      {"Algiers,Algeria",36.83,3.0},
      {"Amarillo,TX,USA",35.18,-101.83},
      {"Amsterdam,Netherlands",52.37,4.88},
      {"Anchorage,AK,USA",61.22,-149.9},
      {"Ankara,Turkey",39.92,32.92},
      {"Asuncion,Paraguay",-25.25,-57.67},
      {"Athens,Greece",37.97,23.72},
      {"Atlanta,GA,USA",33.75,-84.38},
      {"Auckland,New Zealand",-36.87,174.75},
      {"",999,999}};

int main()
{

int j;
int found=0;
char city[MAX_CITY_LEN];
int citySize=(sizeof(places)/sizeof(places[0]));

printf("Please Enter the Name of a City: \n");
scanf_s("%s", &city, MAX_CITY_LEN,stdin);
city[strlen(city)-1]='\0';



for(j=0;j<citySize;j++)
{
     if(strcmp(city,places[j].name)==0)
     {
     found=1;                                
     printf("lat = %f, long = %f",places[j].latitude,places[j].longitude); 
     break;                               
     }
   }
  if(!found)
   printf("City not found");

return 0;

 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? (Using breakpoints and stepping through your loop)

Comment: Try entering "Aberdeen,Scotlandd", then ask yourself why you're doing `city[strlen(city)-1]='\0';` Also, does the program actually *crash*, or does it just terminate normally?

Comment: Your use of `scanf_s` is wrong and the following line is also wrong

Comment: I don't think your scanf captures spaces, so any of those names including spaces will get matched (e.g New Zealand)

Comment: try `scanf_s("%34s", city, MAX_CITY_LEN);` and remove `city[strlen(city)-1]='\0';`

Comment: @MattMcNabb How about fgets(city, MAX_CITY_LEN,stdin); instead of scanf_s.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `"%s"` is fine, the point of `scanf_s` is that you can pass the buffer size as argument

Comment: @AlexMcKean I was about to suggest just that

Comment: @MattMcNabb It does not work is to think of you.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I tried scanf_s("%34s", city, MAX_CITY_LEN); with no luck. I'm thinking it might be something wrong in my for loop.

Comment: @AlexMcKean read the upvoted comment by Keith Thompson

Comment: @AlexMcKean Did you delete the line of the `city[strlen(city)-1]='\0';`?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yeah I deleted the line and I'm still getting City not found when I enter in the data.

Comment: @KeithThompson I deleted that Line and still seem to be getting City not found when I enter in my data. I also have included fgets instead of scanf_s.

Comment: @AlexMcKean Do you be entered in full name, including the nationality? You need to cut out the city name in the search at the time when only the city name.

Comment: Print your input before you enter the loop. It works for me if I enter "Aberdeen,Scotland". Also beware its matching the exact string so its case and space sensitive. You can add getch(); before return to pause and see your output.

Comment: `fgets` retains the `'\n'` from the input line. `scanf_s` does not. If I delete the `city[strlen(city)-1]='\0';` from your original code *and make no other changes*, then enter `Aberdeen,Scotland`, it matches.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes, I just need the city name. How would I go about just looking it up via city name and not the full (country,nationality)

Comment: @AlexMcKean Either Split the city and country into 2 strings in your struct or match the substring up to but not including the comma. I think the former option is easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
int found=0;
char city[MAX_CITY_LEN];
int citySize=(sizeof(places)/sizeof(places[0]));
int j, len;

printf("Please Enter the Name of a City: \n");
scanf_s("%34s", city, MAX_CITY_LEN);

len = strlen(city);
for(j=0;j<citySize;j++){
    if(strncmp(city, places[j].name, len)==0 && places[j].name[len]==','){
        found=1;                                
        printf("lat = %f, long = %f",places[j].latitude,places[j].longitude); 
        break;                               
    }
}
if(!found)
    printf("City not found");
```

Comment: Thanks this got the program running properly. I was able to use it in my distance calculation program to find distance between cities!